# Artefact behind master view controller in split view controller

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5.1

I have a problem on iOS 5.1 with split view controller. On the portrait orientation I see some gradient artefact behind the master view controller at the bottom. I tried to play with it and noticed that it appeared only when master view controller is actually a navigation controller. This is code from the default master-detail application:

```
MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];

DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;    
[self.splitViewController setViewControllers:@[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController]];

[self.window setRootViewController:self.splitViewController];
```

The only thing what I changed in code is that I set masterViewController.tableView.alpha = 0.1f to show you this strange gradient artefact behind the table (when alpha set to 1.0f I see only a short part of this artefact at the right)

On iOS 6 everything works perfectly, the problem happened only on iOS 5.1, but my app should support old versions of iOS also. Is this a documented bug of the iOS SDK or there's something managed wrong?

Thanks in advance

[image: the screenshot]